# Defining the rotation axis independent of the origin

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, geometric-transform

I tried to rotate a 3D object in `Graphics3D` using `GeometricTransformations` with `RotationMatrix`.

Unfortunately, I could only define a vector as rotation axis which goes through the origin: for instance, `RotationMatrix [angle, {0, 1, 0}]` gives a Rotation around the y-axis.

Is it possible to define a rotation axis independent of the point of origin, like on the axis that includes points $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$?

Comment: In space you have three parameters `RotationTransform[\[Theta],w,p]`: Axes `w` through `p`

Answer (score 4):

- We use `p0+RotationMatrix[t,p1-p0].(pt-p0)`  to rotate the point `pt` around the axis `p0,p1`.

```
p0 = {1, 1, 0};
p1 = {1, 0, 0};
pt = {1, 2, 3};
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Blue, 
   p0 + RotationMatrix[t, p1 - p0] . (pt - p0) // Point, Red, 
   AbsoluteThickness[8], InfiniteLine[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> 5, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
  ViewPoint -> p1 - p0 + {.1, .1, .1}], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g3 = Cuboid[];
g4 = GeometricTransformation[
   g3, (RotationTransform[#, {0, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0}] & /@ 
     Range[π/6, 3 π/2, π/6])];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Lighter@Cyan, g3
  , Pink, Opacity[0.3], g4
  , Opacity[1, Black]
  , Thick, Arrow[{{3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0}}]
  }
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
 , SphericalRegion -> True
 ]
```

[image]